# Disable password change email to user, send via another mailing service

Tags: php, wordpress

I'm looking to disable the standard "You have reset your password" email in Wordpress for a user.

Is it possible to expand on that? I'm pretty sure the following disables the email:

```
/**
 * Disable User Notification of Password Change Confirmation
 */
add_filter( 'send_password_change_email', '__return_false' );
```

Could I combine that with something else when that fires?

Essentially I want to use another mailing service to send the email using the following:

```
$this->sendinblue_send_template($customer_email, 6);
```

So how can I combine the two and use my snippet of code when the password change email fires?

Comment: why not just overwrite that method via a plugin and use that? o.O

Comment: @treyBake Could it just be done in the functions file?

Comment: I'd personally make an extension - as it's extending the core functionality

Answer (score 0):

I suggest you to build an [plugin](https://codex.wordpress.org/Writing_a_Plugin), this is the code to build an plugin that you need
and you can using this [filter](https://codex.wordpress.org/Plugin_API/Filter_Reference/send_password_change_email) like this:

```
// define the send_password_change_email callback 
function filter_send_password_change_email( $send, $user, $userdata ) { 
    $send = false;

    // write the code if you want to send to other email provider

    return $send; 
}; 

// add the filter 
add_filter( 'send_password_change_email', 'filter_send_password_change_email', 10, 3 );
```

Comment: Thanks, can't that just be used in the functions file though? I'm not using any plugins so for the sake of neatness I'd like to keep it within the functions.

Comment: hai @Rob if you want to edit the core of the function you can update in this file https://github.com/WordPress/WordPress/blob/51814d68af6310644c37981491225b9d8b95f6f2/wp-includes/user.php#L1963 . But i don't recomend it, because if you change it you can't update your wordpress. Because the rule of thumb in wordpress is about the plugin